# Cannot use Cmd+Enter in Google result page to open links in new tabs after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-yosemite

I enabled Google result page's shortkeys, so when searching for something, in the result page, pressing down arrow on my keyboard would make the pointer arrow to point to the first result, and that arrow can be moved up & down using arrow keys. If you have shortkeys enabled in Google's settings, you'd know what I'm talking about.

[image: screenshot]

Before upgrading to Mac OSX Yosemite, I always used Cmd+Enter to open links that the arrow is pointing at, but this stopped working right after I upgraded to Yosemite - nothing happens when I press the key combination.

I just tested this as well: in stackoverflow.com, press tab to select something, and when pressing Cmd+Enter, it doesn't open. But I used this key comb to open selected links in new tabs all the time.

Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: Same for me, but I'm not sure if it's a Yosemite bug, a Chrome bug, or a Google Search bug? Cmd-Enter in the Omnibox still opens a new tab, and the Cmd-Enter key events are still getting through to the page.

Comment: It's not a Yosemite problem because I was using cmd+enter with Yosemite. I think it's broken with the latest update of chrome. I couldn't find any solution though...

Comment: Yes, pretty sure that this issue occurs with the latest Chrome upgrade. I am using Mavericks and just noticed this issue in the last week or two, and only with Chrome. Firefox works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+Enter (and Cmd+Enter) should be fixed in the next Beta:

- [Ctrl+Enter does not open link in background tab](http://crbug.com/450069)

But also see:

- [Command + Enter / Ctrl-Shift-Enter no longer opens focused links in a new tab](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451060)
- [Alt+Enter no longer downloads the target of a focused link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=454218)
- [Extension behavior to open a link in a new background tab goes wrong](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=454222)

Answer (score -1):

Try this new [Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mac-www-com/eaocdmdcibhhjodgondbpnmblddadikn)

Install the plugin - No configuration.
Enter any keyword in address bar and add "]" for .com and "]]" for .net

Example:
1) Enter yahoo] and press enter key. You will be taken to www.yahoo.com
2) Enter apple]] and press enter key. You will be taken to www.apple.net

Comment: This does not answer OP.